# Styles not working in isomorphic React implementation using webpack

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Server rendered html does not contain any css. Only when react runs on client side, the css gets applied. What am i doing wrong?

### Webpack config server + client: (shortened for brevity)

```
module.exports = [
  {
    name: "simple-server",
    entry: [path.join(__dirname, "..", "src", "server.js")],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "..", "build"),
      filename: "server.js",
      libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
    },
    target: "node",
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          loaders: ["css", "sass"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: ["css"],
        }
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx", ".scss"],
      modulesDirectories: [ "src", "node_modules"],
    },
  },
  {
    name: "simple-client",
    context: path.join(__dirname, "..", "src"),
    entry: {
      app: ["handlers/App", "webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=__webpack_hmr"],
    },
    devtool: "cheap-module-inline-source-map",
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "..", "build", "assets"),
      filename: "[name].js",
      publicPath: "assets/",
    },
    target: "web",
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          loaders: ["style-loader","css-loader?sourceMap","postcss-loader","sass-loader?sourceMap"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loaders: ["style-loader","css-loader?sourceMap","postcss-loader"],
        }
      ],
    },
    postcss: () => [autoprefixer({ browsers: ["last 5 versions", "> 5%"] })],
    resolve: {
      extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx", ".scss"],
      modulesDirectories: [
        "src",
        "node_modules",
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "app.html",
        template: "templates/main.html",
      })
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ],
  },
];
```

### Sample component :

```
import React from "react";
import "Styles.scss";

export default Component extends .... {}
```

Comment: When you view the page, can you see the reference to the css file on the dom? and what do you see in the network tab? Is it trying to load it and fail?

Comment: @Geraint No I don't see any css files/inline styles being injected in html. Styles only seem to be present in .js which is rendered client side.

Comment: Try manually putting a link to the css in your index html page (think you've called it app.html) and see if that works (just to determine if it is the problem)

Comment: I'm not extracting the style into any .css file as of now. If i did, i would be loading the styles twice (jsx + css file). How can I work it both on client & server (probably by extracting styles into head) and still enjoy benefits of hmr?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell webpack to create separate bundle for css when it creates js bundle. And use them in html head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css">
```

(There are many articles which suggest that it is better to have css in the head of html).

How to instruct webpack to separate css:

https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html#separate-css-bundle

#### In short:

You have to install :

```
npm install extract-text-webpack-plugin --save
```

Add this plugin to plugin list:

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css")
]
```

And in loaders:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")
},
{
  test: /\.sass$/,
  loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!sass-loader")
}
```

Im not sure if this works correctly with hmr (reloading css) because when I work with hmr Im not need server side rendering. 
I have two webpack configs : dev and production. dev config use hmr and doesn't separate css (one bundle) and doesn't render server side. And production doesn't use hmr, have separated css and js and server side rendering.

You could check my configuration:

https://github.com/uhlryk/my-express-react-seed

Comment: This might not be the best approach. I haven't figured a solution yet, but this answer makes sense - http://stackoverflow.com/a/36023446/2645080